# How to prevent Quartz scheduler from missing few executions

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

We have quartz scheduler to trigger the jenkins job which will be created on the fly through Jenkins create API.
So I have placed my create jenkins job API call inside the execute internal method.When multiple parallel requests are made, sometimes all the requests are picked up for execution and sometimes few are missed.
The count of missed executions differs. 
How do I make this stop and make quartz to run all of my requests.

Tried increasing the thread count and misfire threshold but the issue exists

Comment: Refer to setting the misfire instruction to the trigger https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html

Comment: Yes I did look into that but my trigger looks this way 
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
      .withIdentity(changePoolNameTriggerKey).startAt(new DateTime()
        .plusSeconds(configuration.getInt(JobConstants.execution_latency)).toDate().build();
              
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

And If I include the withSchedule it throws error. How exactly do I modify the above statements to execute the missed executions

Comment: Please put the code block in the question

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you need is to set the correct misfire instruction based on your business logic and type of trigger

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger() .
    withIdentity(changePoolNameTriggerKey).
    startAt(new DateTime().plusSeconds(configuration.getInt(JobConstants.execution_latency)).
    toDate().
    build(); 


((MutableTrigger) trigger).setMisfireInstruction(MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW)
```

Comment: So I tried and I see the same behavior. Executions are still getting missed

Comment: Please put your complete code in the question to help furthur